# python selenium open browser in other file

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem in my Selenium project (python language).
In one of the test classes, he writes to the variable the address of the page where he is currently located.
I need this variable to be invoked in a different class - the page has to be opened.

```
class EditFirst():

    def testFirst(self):
        url2 = self.browser.current_url
```

and second class, when I should open url2

```
 class EditSecond():

        def testSecond(self):
            #uri2
```

The second class does not see the variable. Classes are in separate files.

Comment: of course :  browser.get("uri2") in second class, soory

Comment: These are two separate tests? Why does one test need a URL generated in the other test? What are you really trying to test?

Comment: The two tests are separate. In the first test I test whether a given function correctly edits the form, I change the data. In the second test, he tries to delete the form. It is removed, but for certainty I want to call the address after deletion, to check if this element is present. I do not have access to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: don't.

**1. Isolate your tests.** Tests shouldn't depend on the output of other tests. Doing so makes them brittle and prevents them from being run independently (which, interestingly, is [the original definition of a unit test](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/what-is-a-unit-test-the-answer-might-surprise-you)).

**2. Group execution and assertion.** In this case, it sounds like your "tests" are actually the phases of *a single test*:

1. setup (e.g., creating a resource that you can later delete),
2. execution (e.g., deleting the test resource) and
3. assertion (e.g., verifying that the resource was deleted).

If, in a test, you wish to (3) assert that a URL is inaccessible after a resource is deleted, the test should also (2) perform the deletion. But before it can do that, it’ll have to (1) create a resource that it can delete.

All of these are different phases of a single test. Using these three phases in a single test (a) makes the test less brittle and (b) makes it clear precisely what steps are necessary to produce the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question. When I have application with empty database. My test automation - They should be dependent on each other?

Comment: @MateuszNerkowski No, your tests should never be dependent on each other. If you’re testing that a user can delete a resource, your test setup should create a resource that it can then delete.

Comment: I understand thank you for answer. I could ask for a solution to the problem I presented.
Yes for the future :)